# gcm on rails 4.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, google-cloud-messaging

I am using rails 4.0.0 and I am trying to use google cloud messaging for androids.

I already tryed to use
https://github.com/dondeng/gcm_on_rails (bugged, and not for rails 4.0)
https://github.com/spacialdb/gcm (ssl error)
...github.com/push-notification/crusade_rails (too complex and i think it uses another gem)
...github.com/ileitch/rapns (i think it uses the /spacialdb/gcm gem, and i cant find the sending method)

soo, all of them somehow fail...

I just want a simple gem to send a notification for androids (plural).
should i just try to use gcm on my own?

thank u

EDIT:
im trying /spacialdb/gcm from scratch again,
and it gives me error code 401, from the troubleshoot i see:

```
Authorization header missing or with invalid syntax. 
#since i am using the gem, dont think this is the problem

Invalid project number sent as key. 
#i am not sure if it is the Project Number or the API KEY, however i tryed the 3 options
Key valid but with GCM service disabled.
#dont think soo, cause on APIs, Google Cloud Messaging for Android appears ON
Request originated from a server not whitelisted in the Server Key IPs. #I try both on localhost and on heroku
```

Comment: If you, or anyone else, are interested, I pushed up a minor fix to make `gcm_on_rails` compatible with Rails 4. It is in [our fork](https://github.com/fluentsolutions/gcm_on_rails/tree/rails_4_update) for the moment; at the time of this comment, I've only just made the pull request, so the original owner has not merged it yet (in fact they haven't merged in anything for almost 2 years now for some reason...)